# Hyper V 2008 enterprise not fully utilising system memory

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have 4 VM's running on hyper v 2008 R2 enterprise. Two of them have a warning memory status. Thus both have more memory demand than assigned memory.

But On windows the physical memory usage is only 12gb. The server has 32GB.

How can I get Hyper V to use more system memory?

Comment: Are the VM's using static or dynamic memory? Does the memory demand exceed the provisioned or maximum memory for the VM's?

Comment: Yes, all are on dynamic. None are over the maximum allowed.

Comment: According to performance monitor, Hyper v has about 22Gb of available ram of the server's 32GB currently. But the 4'vms use: 5, 0.5, 2.4 and 1 respectivly.

Comment: Well you didn't really answer my questions. Does the memory demand of the virtual machines exceed the allocated/provisioned memory for those virtual machines? If so, then you need to allocate/provision more memory to the virtual machines. Hyper-V will not grant more memory to the virtual machines than what is allocated/provisioned.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add it clearly enough. No None of the VM's memory demand is over their maximum allowed/allocated/provisioned memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have free space on the disk where your snapshots are stored. In the case of failure, Hyper-V will pause the VM and write the RAM to the snapshot folder. If there isn't enough available disk space to write a complete snapshot, then Hyper-V will not add more RAM.

When adding RAM fails because of this, you'll see events in the event log on the Hyper-V host.